# How to run a ScalaTest form a different project in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, scala, scalatest, scala-ide

I have two Scala projects open in Eclipse (the Scala IDE, more precisely). One project is the main project and the other is where I want to place my tests.

If I place a test file (i.e. a `class Test1 extends FlatSpec`) in my main project, I can right click on the file and choose "Run Configurations", and it offers me to "Run as ScalaTest - File". However, if I copy that same test file to the second project, right clicking doesn't offer that option. Why is that?

If I am not explaining the situation with enough detail, I'll be glad to add more information.

Comment: Do you have any compilation errors? Are both projects successfully built?

Comment: Hi. No, no compiler errors in either project. It is a complete mistery to me. However, I made a third project and created all the classes again from scratch, and it worked fine, so I guess I'll never know...

Answer (score 1):

From ScalaTest guide:

> Using ScalaTest in a Scala project
>
> > To use ScalaTest in your Scala
> >     project, you must download ScalaTest and include it in build path of
> >     your project.

If it is in your build path, you could just create run-configurations for that particular class.

I've had problems in the past with eclipse and not seeing run java application. I just created the run configurations myself.

Comment: I tried doing that, but failed. Do you happen to know the important details that must be included in a ScalaTest run configuration?

Comment: @Gonzalo Is scala test in your build path?

Comment: Yes, I have added a ScalaTest jar file to both my projects.

Comment: Although ideally I would only have to add ScalaTest to my testing project. However, since it's not working in my testing project, I have the test classes in the main project also.

Comment: @Gonzalo What options is eclipse giving you when you right click and look at `Run As`

Comment: It said "no options applicable". However, I created a third project an created all the test classes again, from scratch, and it worked. A mystery...